# change row color if row value is negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table where I have to highlight negative values. So I tried using jQuery and did not get my desire output. Lets suppose I have a table like this.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">1</div>
        <td class>Received</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">-50</div>
        <td class>Received</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">0</div>
        <td class>Received</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">20</div>
        <td class>Received</div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using jQuery. But its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
    $("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(.status.val()<0).closest('tr.alt').css('background-color', '#cd0000');
    $(td.status[value<0]).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: `$(.status.val()<0)` Do you want to invent a new selector?

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid, you need closing tag `</td>` instead of `</div>`

Comment: Thats's not the way to check val()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $( ".status" ).each(function(){
       var value = parseInt( $( this ).html() );
       if ( value < 0 )
       {
           $( this ).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it as below.

As you said number goes negative then you can also check for `-` sign in html.

```
$('tr.alt td:contains("-")').parent('tr').css('background-color', '#cd0000');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function in jQuery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJVak/)

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">1</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">-50</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">0</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">20</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".status" )
      .filter(function(){
         return $(this).html() < 0;
      })
      .parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem in you selector..

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
   $("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
   $('.status').each(function(){
      var $this =$(this); 
     if($this.text() < 0){
        $this.parent().css('background-color', '#cd0000');
        $this.css('background-color', 'red');
     } 
  }) 

});
```

or using filter()

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
   $("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
   $( ".status" ).filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() < 0;
   }).css('background-color', 'red').parent().css('background-color', '#cd0000');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
  $("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
  $("td" ).each(function() {
     if(parseInt($(this).text())<0)
     {
       $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#cd0000');
       $(this).css("background-color", "red");
     }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">

<tr class="alt">
<td class="status">1</td>
<td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td class="status">-50</td>
<td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td class="status">0</td>
<td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td class="status">20</td>
<td class>Received</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyb5d/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the HTML posted is off the top of your head? Because you have a lot of mismatched tags there. Fixed:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">1</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">-50</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">0</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td class="status">20</td>
        <td class>Received</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, I would move styles to a stylesheet (it makes everything easier to manage):

```
tr.alt:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
tr.alt:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fcfceb;
}
tr.alt.bad {
    background-color: #cd0000;
}
```

Then, selectors don't quite work that way, though you can query the rows and iterate the result. Also, .val() is for form fields; you want .text().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.status').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (Number($this.text()) < 0)
            $this.parent().addClass('bad');
    });
});
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/MBDKY/